# Stripe.js conflicting only when put into lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe.js to add a card to a customer. I have successfully done this on a standard page, but now I look at it, there is so little information on the page, I'd like to put it in a lightbox. I have transferred all the relevant script inclusions I had from the main site header to the lightbox header but it's conflicting somewhere and I can't work out why.

These are all the script includes in my original header:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/admin_general.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tipped/excanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tipped/spinners.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tipped/tipped.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Stripe.setPublishableKey("my_key_here");
</script>
```

...and this is the script includes in my new header:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tipped/excanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tipped/spinners.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tipped/tipped.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Stripe.setPublishableKey("my_key_here");
</script>
```

(obviously my key is actually in there)

This works fine when loaded directly into a browser window, but when the exact same page is loaded into the colorbox it gives me the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined
```

I've tried delaying the setting of the key until the document is ready, in case it was trying to set the key before stripe.js was loaded, but nothing I've tried works... and since it works fine directly in a browser window it has to be that it's conflicitng with something, but what? This happens in exactly the same way if I remove all traces and inclusions of the tipped js script.

This is really frustrating, can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out. I needed to include `{iframe:true}` to the colorbox options to ensure that the content acted on its own without interference from the page it was being loaded from, hence the conflict.

Phew!